# Update Dictionary with same values and different keys

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries with different keys but can have same values.

```
dict1 = {key1:[['abc','12'],['xyz','34'],['pqr',[56]]],key2:[['name','lin'],['age','yes']]}


dict_2 = {key3: '(( value(abc) = literal(12) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))'}
```

If you see both the dictionaries have values that might repeat in both. What I am trying to achieve is : Replace `value` in `dict_2` with key of `dict_1`.

The output I am expecting is:

```
dict_2 = {key3:'(key1 or value(like) = literal(music) )....'}
```

I can do dict manipulations with same keys but can figure out in case of different keys but same values.

**Edit:**
Few things that I noticed to be considered:

1. The operator between `value` and `literal` is also has to be considered . For example `abc > 10` now that should also be replaced as it the meeting the criteria as value of `abc = 12` which is actually greater than 10.
2. As @DirtyBit suggested, I only intend to replace part of the value on dict_2.

So, I have tried adding regex to my code to split the element and it works as expected but still not able to replace with matching key in dict_1:

```
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(dict1.items(), dict_2.items()):
    #print(v2)
    for element in re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\))[\s=<>(?:in)]+[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\)))',v2):
       # print(element)
        print(k2, ": ", v2.replace(element, k))
```

Comment: The syntax for `dict1` and `dict_2` is incorrect.

Comment: Also the values are not repeating in both the dicts.

Comment: Also from what it looks like, you are not intending to change the `value` with the `key` but a **part** of the `value` with a `key`.

Comment: @DirtyBit yes exactly a part of value with key. But the catch is the `value` and `literal ` are kind of my data types. lets lay I only want to replace them if the type is `value` and `literal`

Comment: see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from the comments from the quesiton:

```
dict1 = {
         'key1':[['abc','12'],['xyz','34'],['pqr',[56]]],
         'key2':[['name','lin'],['age','yes']]
        }


dict_2 = {
          'key3': '(( value(abc) = literal(12) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))',
          'key4': '(( value(abc) = literal(12) or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))'
         }

res = {}
# desired
# dict_2 = {key3:'(key1 or value(like) = literal(music) )....'}
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(dict1.items(), dict_2.items()):
    print(k2, ": ", v2.replace("( value(abc) = literal(12)", k))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
key3 :  (key1 or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))
key4 :  (key2 or value(like) = literal(music) ) and (value(PRICELIST) in propval(valid))
```

Comment: what you have given is exactly what I am trying to achieve. But can't it be more concrete like it won't be always abc and 12. It can be anything from dcit_2.

Comment: Something like `if 'value' and 'literal' in dict_2 : loop through them` . e.g (abc,12),(like,music) and them look for them in dict_1

Comment: as the value is a big string and we are only concerned with value and literal part. Do you think we might need to apply some regex hare

Comment: @Duck_dragon Indeed, you could `split` the value and literal or use regex to get their values and check if it exists in the `dict1`, only then do the rest

Comment: I think split would be good because I need to do some other operations for those not  value and literal. But thats a different topic

Comment: Can you help with the making it more flexible like the replace part. I am trying from my end but can help will be good

Comment: @Duck_dragon Sure, just give me some time!

Comment: Just some info. I have found some exception cases like `value(ExternalScaleVal) < literal(1)`. Seems like we need to consider the operator also. In `dict1` it could be `['ExternalScaleVal','2']`. Sorry for letting you know this late but I noticed it just now

Comment: @Duck_dragon Could you add that in that question to make it crystal for everyone?

Comment: Yes, adding. I should have added it after noticing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189867/discussion-between-duck-dragon-and-dirtybit).

Comment: I got the regex to find individual values.

Comment: `re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\))[\s=<>(?:in)]+[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\()[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(?:\)))', item)`. This will work

Comment: @Duck_dragon looks promising, did it solve your problem?

Comment: yes It gives the expected output. Bu having issues with evaluating with items in dict1

Comment: @Duck_dragon Great, kindly add the latest snippet to your code. I'm off the desk so will look into to tomorrow morning. Cheers

Comment: okay , I will add that to the existing code . Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry for checking in late. Have you got something relevant